Jenkins, how stop the job when one of the parallel branches fails? (failfast seems not to work)
My code is like
    stage('compile and clone') {
            steps {
                script {
                    tasks = BUILD_TASKS.split(',')
                    def jobs = [:]
                    for (arg in tasks) {
                        jobact = {
                            ...
                            build job: 'xxx', parameters: jobparam[arg], propagate: false
                            ...
                        }
                        jobs[arg] = jobact
                    }
                    parallel jobs
                }
            }
        
        }
                    

And I want that if one of the build job fails, stop the entire task.
Although I add
    options {
        parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
    }

the parallel tasks will not stop until all the branches finish.

Sometimes in Jenkins, even with the parallelsAlwaysFailFast() option, parallel stages might not terminate immediately upon a failure if some tasks are still running. To enforce an immediate stop when any job fails, you can structure your pipeline to handle failures more explicitly by checking the result of each parallel job and aborting the entire pipeline if any job fails.
stage('compile and clone') {
    steps {
        script {
            tasks = BUILD_TASKS.split(',')
            def jobs = [:]
            boolean hasFailed = false

            for (arg in tasks) {
                jobs[arg] = {
                    try {
                        build job: 'xxx', parameters: jobparam[arg], propagate: true
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "Build failed for task: ${arg}"
                        hasFailed = true
                        error("Stopping parallel execution due to failure.")
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                parallel jobs
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (hasFailed) {
                    error("Pipeline failed due to one or more parallel jobs failing.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This approach might help stop the pipeline as soon as any parallel job fails.

I tried try{                         parallel jobs                     }catch (Exception e) {                         error "stop"                     }but it still does not work
